# Loading Scikit-Learn Pipeline Steps from JSON

Tags: python, json, loops, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am a newbie to Python and ML, so please bear with me.

I’m trying to programmatically generate scikit-learn pipeline steps based on parameters in a JSON file.

The Parameters are as follows:

```
{
    "scaler": ["STAN", "MINMAX", "MAXABS", "ROBUST", "PT"],
    "imbalance": ["SMOTE", "RUS", "SMOTEENN"],
    "classifier": ["SVM", "RF", "GBC"]
}
```

I’m trying to loop through each of the lists, starting with the scaler and adding pipeline steps with each iteration.
The goal is to have one pipeline for each possible combination.

The following loops will provide me with the some output:

```
complete_pipelines = []
pipeline_steps = []
for scaler in scalerList:
    pipeline_steps.append(scaler)

    for imbalancer in imbalancerList:
        pipeline_steps.append(imbalancer)

        for classifier in classifierList:
            pipeline_steps.append(classifier)

            if (len(pipeline_steps) == 3):
                complete_pipelines.append(pipeline_steps)
                pipeline_steps = []
                pipeline_steps.append(scaler)
                pipeline_steps.append(imbalancer)
```

What I am getting with the above method is:

```
[
  ['STAN', 'SMOTE', 'SVM'], 
  ['STAN', 'SMOTE', 'RF'], 
  ['STAN', 'SMOTE', 'GBC']
]
```

Which is a start, but what I am looking for is:

```
[
  [“STAN”, “SMOTE”, “SVM”]
  [“STAN”, “SMOTE”, “RF”]
  [“STAN”, “SMOTE”, “GBC”]
  [“STAN”, “RUS”, “SVM”]
  [“STAN”, “RUS”, “RF”]
  [“STAN”, “RUS”, “GBC”]
  [“STAN”, “SMOTEENN”, “SVM”]
  [“STAN”, “SMOTEENN”, “RF”]
  [“STAN”, “SMOTEENN”, “GBC”]

  [“MINMAX”, “SMOTE”, “SVM”]
  [“MINMAX”, “SMOTE”, “RF”]
  [“MINMAX”, “SMOTE”, “GBC”]
  .
  .
  .
  [“PT”, “SMOTEENN”, “SVM”]
  [“PT”, “SMOTEENN”, “RF”]
  [“PT”, “SMOTEENN”, “GBC”]
]
```

After these lists are generated I will go through each of the lists and set up the pipelines accordingly. 
But just getting this to work has already stumped me…

I’d appreciate any pointers on how to implement such a loop or if there are any functions to create such sets already “built in”.

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be something like this

```
complete_pipelines = []
for scaler in scalerList:
    for imbalancer in imbalancerList:
        for classifier in classifierList:
            complete_pipelines.append([scaler,imbalancer,classifier ])

print(complete_pipelines)
```

http://ideone.com/tftPGd

Comment: Thanks Nafis for your swift response, but unfortunately this does not solve it. The output would be like this:
[['PT', 'SMOTE', 'SVM', 'RF', 'GBC', 'RUS', 'SVM', 'RF', 'GBC', 'SMOTEENN', 'SVM', 'RF', 'GBC']]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the fast fix and the incredibly simple answer!
Works like a charm and I'm kinda embarrassed not to have come up with this one on my own... Thanks a bunch!